# How to select rows with conditional values of one column in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I have this table:

| id | timeline |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BASELINE |
| 1 | MIDTIME |
| 1 | ENDTIME |
| 2 | BASELINE |
| 2 | MIDTIME |
| 3 | BASELINE |
| 4 | BASELINE |
| 5 | BASELINE |
| 5 | MIDTIME |
| 5 | ENDTIME |
| 6 | MIDTIME |
| 6 | ENDTIME |
| 7 | RISK |
| 7 | RISK |

So this is what the data looks like except the data has more observations (few thousands)

How do I get the output so that it will look like this:

| id | timeline |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BASELINE |
| 1 | MIDTIME |
| 2 | BASELINE |
| 2 | MIDTIME |
| 5 | BASELINE |
| 5 | MIDTIME |

How do I select the first two terms of each ID which has 2 specific timeline values (BASELINE and MIDTIME)? Notice id 6 has MIDTIME and ENDTIME,and id 7 has two RISK I don't want these two ids.

I used

```
SELECT * 
FROM df 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM df GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)=2)
```

and got IDs with two timeline values (output below) but don't know how to get rows with only BASELINE and MIDTIME.

```
id  timeline   
---|--------|
 1 | BASELINE |
 1 | MIDTIME  |
 2 | BASELINE |
 2 | MIDTIME  | 
 5 | BASELINE | 
 5 | MIDTIME  |
 6 | MIDTIME  |    ---- dont want this
 6 | ENDTIME  |    ---- dont want this
 7 | RISK     |    ---- dont want this
 7 | RISK     |    ---- dont want this
```

**Many Thanks.**

Comment: Which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: I am using sql package in R actually.

Comment: Also, do the first two timeline values need to be BASELINE and MIDTIME? If so, how do you order the timeline values?

Comment: Yes. the two values needed to be Baseline and Midtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using exists -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=210b01019a1d73ecd8ce4bc580482814)**

```
    select * from t t1 where timeline in ('BASELINE','MIDTIME') and
    exists
     (select 1 from t t2 where t1.id=t2.id and timeline in ('BASELINE','MIDTIME')
            group by t2.id having count(distinct timeline)=2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  timeline
1   BASELINE
1   MIDTIME
2   BASELINE
2   MIDTIME
5   BASELINE
5   MIDTIME
```

Comment: @Iwishworldpeace, glad that it helped u :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this query should give you the result you want.

NOTE: As i understand, you don't want the ID where exists a "ENDTIME", and in your sample data, there is an "ENDTIME" for ID 1. I assumed this was an error so i made a query that excludes all id containing "ENDTIME".

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        id
    FROM
        df
    WHERE
        timeline IN ('ENDTIME', 'RISK')
)
SELECT
    id,
    timeline
FROM
    df
WHERE
    id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM CTE);
```

Comment: ID 1 has 3 values and only those 2 values with BASELINE and MIDTIME are needed.

Comment: So you only want to exclude the ID 6 for having that value? the ID 6 is the last id (MAX)? If so, it's easy to fix it. If not, you should give more criteria to exlcude ID's more than having the "ENDTIME" value.

Comment: OK, I think I will add more to clarify.

Comment: Got it, define which are all the criterias to bring a record or to exclude it. For Example: IF an ID have BASELINE, MIDTIME and ENDTIME, then should bring BASE and MID but not END. IF an ID have only MIDTIME and ENDTIME should not be included.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a number of ways to do this, here's one way that will pick up BASELINE and MIDTIME rows where only they exist, ensuring there are only 2 rows per returned ID. Without knowing the ordering of timeline, it's not possible to go further I don't think:

```
SELECT
      id
    , timeline
FROM (
    SELECT
          *
        , SUM(CASE WHEN timeline = 'BASELINE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS BaselineCount
        , SUM(CASE WHEN timeline = 'MIDTIME' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS MidtimeCount
    FROM df
    WHERE df.timeline IN ('BASELINE', 'MIDTIME')
) subquery
WHERE subquery.BaselineCount > 0
AND subquery.MidtimeCount > 0
GROUP BY
      id
    , timeline
;
```

Comment: Updated the answer to fix a bug

Comment: `BaselineCount = sum(...)` is invalid standard SQL  (unless there is a column named `BaselineCount` in the table)